# Php, MySql And Webform

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to figure this out for over two days, I am following a youtube tutorial, with a basic sign in for my Android Application, but before I do that I want to test the .php script.

I am thinking that I should get a success when I press the login button but I am getting Invalid credentials, and I know that the username and password is correct

Below is my login.php script.

```
require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //gets user's info based off of a username.
    $query = "SELECT id, username, passwrd
            FROM application_users
            WHERE
                username = :username
        ";
    $query_params = array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username']
    );

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message.
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));

    }

    //This will be the variable to determine whether or not the user's information is correct.
    //we initialize it as false.
    $validated_info = false;

    //fetching all the rows from the query
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    echo $row;
    if ($row) {
        //if we encrypted the password, we would unencrypt it here, but in our case we just
        //compare the two passwords
        if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {
            $login_ok = true;
        }
    }

    // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page
    // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again
    if ($login_ok) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Login successful!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
} else {
?>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        Username:<br />
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
        <br /><br />
        Password:<br />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    </form>
<?php
```

}
?>

So when the script loads and I input the values from the remote MYSQL server, the message comes back as invalid credentials.I just want to make sure my login is successful before I head over to the android part, which would be a big todo in itself.

Comment: Are you sure the data is sent with a post action?

Comment: Done any basic debugging? `var_dump($_POST)` and `var_dump($row)` will show you EXACTLY what php's receiving from your form and from the db. check string lengths, check string contents, etc...

Comment: Never really done any debuggung with PHP, where should I put the var_dump satements.

Comment: @Barry, I think so as I am following a tutorial, what I do know is that in the MYSQL database the password is encrypted, but in my form I am using a standard password, I went into the database and created another user whose password is not encrypted

Comment: You can add it wherever you want, to see what contains the variable in parameter.

Comment: @Marc the variables are correct, when I did a var_dump($row) and var_dump($_POST) the returned results are.  array(2) { ["username"]=> string(6) "shakey" ["password"]=> string(8) "escalade" } array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "15" ["username"]=> string(6) "shakey" ["passwrd"]=> string(8) "escalade" } {"success":0,"message":"Invalid Credentials!"}, and this is exactly what is in the database

Comment: Thanks Marc, with the information you provided, I was able to debug it and found out that in the database table the coulumn field was passwrd for the returned query for $row and the $_Post was password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had the opportunity to test it with a real database, but this should work. You still have to add the `require("config.inc.php");` on the top of the file and I've added a custom database connection. I also work with PDO so the queries may look like different than what you've used so far.

```
<?php
// Database connection
try
{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'myusername', 'mypassword');
    $db->exec('SET CHARACTER SET UTF8');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    //Message in case of error when connecting to the database
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
// *** End database connection




$username = ""; // Initialize value in order to keep its value so the user can still see it in his form

if (isset($_POST['login'])) { // if the "login" button is pressed
    $username = $_POST['username']; // retrieve username value from the form
    $password = $_POST['password']; // retrieve password value from the form

    /* 
    *   If a username is unique then a way to do it is to count how many times
    *  the couple with this username and this password appears in our database.
    */
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) userAmount ".
                            "FROM application_users ".
                            "WHERE username = $username ".
                            "AND password = $password;");

    $query->execute();
    $query->closeCursor();

    $resultAmount = $query->fetch();
    if ($resultAmount['userAmount'] == 0){ // If the couple username-password is unfound
        $message = "Username or password unknown";
    } else {
        $message("Login successful");
    }
}
?>


<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    Username:<br />
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" value="<?php echo($username); ?>" />
    <br/><br/>
    Password:<br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
<a href="register.php">Register</a>
</form>
```